# Finding information from vb.net .exe file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, compiled

I'm making a program for my company and I'm trying to match the look and feel of some old programs the company has. The problem is that I don't have the source code anymore to compare to and just get the information. I've been able to do some measurements and determine some of the things like font size, colors, some of the other stylings, but I'm just wondering is there, for example, a way to get information about the other program that's running and it's form?

I.E. Can I find out if the color that was selected was control dark instead of the darkish grey that I was able to measure and set, or find out if the form is set to be a control box, or find out what font size they used (I've been trying to figure this one out and it's bugging me!!!)

Just some things like that.

Comment: +Hussain please stop changing things away from the right way, how I have it showing now is all of the corrections that were right in what you had put in. and only one of those was something that wasn't already generally accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How old are we talking? If they were written in a .NET language (which dates back to 2002), you could use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to take a look at the source.

If you don't know, it's worth a try. ILSpy will tell you if you're trying to inspect an assembly which it isn't able to open, i.e. wasn't built with .NET.

Comment: I know they're .NET 3.5

Comment: With this program, and a little Ctrl-F action I am able to find what I wanted! Thanks! However, it is worth mentioning that this was from a .exe on disk not one that is currently running, but that's fine for me!

Comment: It's really amazing how much goes into one fairly simple app once it's all compiled with the designer and everything together